# Checking a string in user input using if statement always end up returning the same output. How can it be fixed?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to get the user input and check whether it has 'heads' or 'tails' in it using if statement. But I end up getting the same output.

```
user_input = input('Heads? or Tails? \n')

if 'HEADS' or 'TAILS' in user_input.upper():
    print ('you have chosen', user_input)
else:
    print ('wrong!')
```

Input:

```
random text
```

Expected output:

```
wrong!
```

Output that I get:

```
you have chosen random text
```

Comment: Even though this is a simple and common misconception, given that you asked it in a good way (with MCVE provided), I go +1 for this

Answer (score 2):

`or` does not work that way

```
if 'HEADS' in user_input.upper() or 'TAILS' in user_input.upper():
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the OR operator, you have to treat the latter expression as it's own condition to satisfy:

```
if "HEADS" in user_input.upper() or "TAILS" in user_input.upper():
  print("you have chosen", user_input)
else:
  print("wrong")
```